# Can I swap an electrolytic capacitor with one with a higher voltage?

Tags: capacitor, voltage, repair, ratings

I wish I knew more about this stuff, but alas I do not.  I have a radial lead aluminum electrolytic capacitor (rated 470mF and 25v) that died on me.  Can I swap it out with one rated at 35V, or do I need to get one matching it completely?  It is for a plasma, so if there is chance that 35V could cause more damage, then I would like to know!

Thanks

Comment: Is that mF or $\mu F$? The ones with higher voltage will probably be larger, so space could be an issue, especially if the capacitor is in fact 470 mF.

Comment: I agree, and to elaborate: 1 mF is 1000 μF, so a 470 mF capacitor is HUGE. mF is pronounced milifarad and μF is pronounced microfarad.

Comment: very, very similar question to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13091/high-voltage-capacitor-in-a-low-voltage-system/13093#13093">13091

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that the replacement part is comparable in terms of ESR (equivalent series resistance), rated ripple current and rated hours. Don't use a general-purpose cap (usually rated for 1000 hrs or less, with ripple current specified at 120Hz) instead of a high-performance cap (ripple current specified at 100kHz, ESR in milliohms)

If the original capacitor was used in a high-frequency application (i.e. a capacitor on the output of a switching regulator) putting in a part that is not suited for the task will result in a severely shortened life for the cap and the need to replace it again once it blows up.

In general, going from 25V to 35V won't cause you a problem as long as the above parameters are comparable. Once you start getting above 35V, you'll find less and less high-performance capacitors available (the majority of low ESR parts tend to be 25V or lower).

Comment: That is an excellent point to bring up, but his cap is rated in mF (!!), so I doubt this is a high-performance ceramic chip capacitor.

Comment: I don't think he meant millifarads. I think he meant microfarads. Also, my discussion above is specific to aluminum electrolytic caps (I have different advice for ceramic caps.)

Comment: @AdamLawrence What advice would that be in regard to ceramic caps? I have to use caps with the same capacitance in 40V and 5V circuits. Now I'm thinking, I could only buy ceramic capacitors rated for 63V, use them in both circuits and be ok... Anything I should to keep in mind here?

Comment: @fscheidl Post that as your own question.

Answer (score 3):

The rating is a maximum voltage rating. It is not like the current rating of a fuse, the higher the rating, the better. There is normally an increase in cost from the person building them, this increase is negligible to you as a person purchasing only a couple.

You can place that one in and should actually have a smaller chance of blowing it again, this is a good thing.

Comment: Is there any reason why would a fuse with higher voltage rating be a bad replacement for a fuse with lower voltage rating? From what I've read (do correct me if my sources are wrong), the voltage rating of the fuse shows the highest voltage on which the fuse is guaranteed to be able to open the circuit.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, Fuse voltage rating is fine also. I assumed the advice about matching rating had been received because increasing the current rating of a fuse is poor practice. I will edit that in.

Comment: The real issue with a higher voltage rating is not cost, but the design trade-offs, such as a higher ESR and larger package.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a higher Vdc rating on e-Caps implies a lower ESR and higher ripple currents allowed somewhat, but when I rechecked the range of ripple cap in all of DigiKey's stock for those values, the range in ripple current spread over a 6:1 ratio in ripple current.... and that does not include unspecified Chinese cap sales on Ebay.

So what does that mean? if the design requires high ripple current and is not rated for it, then it can over heat and fail as well excess AC voltage ripple.

- "can you replace them ?" sure
- "Should you ?"

  - well that depends on the original part number specified
  - and the pertinent ESR, loss tangent or ripple current specs.

Comment: Tony, this is for a monitor so does ripple current matter with this? And I'm not going to get cheap eBay caps, I was gonna get them at my local radio shack and the 35V variant is all they had.

Comment: @CameronShoudt Sorry, my crystal ball is getting a little dusty so I can't see into your local radio shack all that well.

Comment: If they are only 50 cents like most, nothing to loose, if you want the best... http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EEU-TP1V471B/P15709CT-ND/3831076

Comment: @Tony Stewart Ok, I was hoping for something local and I have a radio Shack literally a mile down the road but these were what I'm looking at https://www.radioshack.com/products/radioshack-1000uf-35v-20-radial-lead-electrolytic-capacitor and https://www.radioshack.com/products/radioshack-470uf-35v-20-radial-lead-electrolytic-capacitor

Comment: if you must not compromise convenience and cost , then not much to loose for trying it, except time.

Comment: i got this monitor for a dollar so if i loose it it doesnt matter but your saying i should just go for it and it may or may not work.