# 12V relay with capacitor resistor - need some guidance

Tags: capacitor, resistors

I am considering using the following example
https://www.the12volt.com/relays/relaydiagram43.html

to use a 12v relay to generate a pulsed ground. However I have zero experience with capacitors, resistors etc (although i bought a bunch of resistors awhile back in case i might need them).

Anyway I am hoping someone can point me to what capacitor to use (electrolytic/ceramic etc) and how to properly wire this. Also can either the cap or resistor be wired backwards?

Would love to know more about all the numbers on capacitors to determine more but not sure where to find the info (yes ive been googling)

Thanks in advance for any insights.

---

[image: pic of cap and resistor]

So here is a picture of how i connected the cap and resistor - i tied them together

ran positive of capacitor to pin 85 on relay
ran negative of capacitor to pin 87 of relay

relay pin 86 is 12v power
relay pin 30 is supposed to be where pulsed ground for 1/2 second is when 12v is removed from pin 86

doesn't seem to work as i connected relay pin 30 to the negative side of a buzzer (while its positive connection was connected to a different 12v location)

Comment: Try aluminum electrolytic, they are inexpensive in that range.

Comment: Do not connect an electrolytic capacitor backwards (unless you're wearing eye protection).  100% guarantee it will smoke & likely explode

Answer (score 1):

That’s an interesting example relay circuit, what do you plan to use it for? This context is probably needed to answer the part of your question about proper wiring.

There are lots of good intros available for Capacitors (e.g., https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/capacitors/all). The link includes a section about identification.

Kyle B’s advice in the comments is important. Some capacitors are reversible and some are not. Smoke and explosive hot goo the likely result of getting that wrong https://hackaday.com/2011/05/18/blowing-up-capacitors/

Resistors on the other hand can be reversed. Again plenty of tutorials e.g., https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/resistors/all

**Edit:** Updated with information based on the comments. The relay circuit referenced in the question was:

[image: Relay Circuit Diagram]

[image: Fixed Polarised Capacitor symbol]

The symbol used for the capacitor represents a *fixed polarised capacitor* of [1K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-) (i.e., 1000) micro-[farad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad)s. Where a farad is the SI unit for capacitance, and the symbol [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-) is the SI symbol for micro (the greek letter mu looks like a u with a long tail). The asymmetrical symbol reminds us to plug the negative side of the capacitor (curved side of the symbol) to the negative or ground side of the circuit, and the positive side of the capacitor (flat side of the symbol) to the positive side of the circuit. Polarized capacitors (e.g., electrolytic) usually have clear marking showing which side is which.

[Capacitors are selected](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/selecting-voltage-rating-for-capacitors) to exceed the maximum voltage of the circuit they'll be installed in. The rated voltage is also often marked on the capacitor.

So you could select something like a 16V 1KuF electrolytic capacitor. In the picture below you'll see that the negative side is marked with the vertical white chevron stripe down the can, with a minus symbol on it, pointing at the negative leg.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much I will definitely read those links. The relay would be used to output a pulsed ground when 12v ignition is pulled from the relay. This pulse wil then go to another module to play an mp3 file in a module for a headlight chime reminder

Comment: @ddrumguy That sounds interesting, so using the capacitor and resistor marked in the schematic https://www.the12volt.com/12voltimages/constgtomg.gif are you all good to go? Remember to post back what you learn.

Comment: i certainly will, once i read through those links and determine what capacitor to order and try

Comment: ok, i now have a capacitor, resistor connected to the relay as listed in the diagram however not seeing any change on my meter and not hearing any click from the relay.

can someone help me understand if i am testing this correctly?

Comment: @ddrumguy Are you able to update /edit your question with a photo, and be very specific about the connections and power for your test?

Comment: i will be near it tomorrow and will post a photo with clear connection info. Thanks for the help

Comment: just dawned on me... how do i add a picture?

Comment: There’s a FAQ about uploading pictures. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links

Comment: to post the picture i had to create an answer - hopefully thats ok

Comment: @ddrumguy - Hi, No it is definitely *not* OK to add new information in an answer. That is forbidden on Stack Exchange sites - answers must *answer* the original question. As *RowanP* said, you should edit any new information into the question i.e. update the question (see the "Edit" link below the question? That is what you should use.) I will move your answer into the question as an edit (i.e. update) this time. Stack Exchange sites have different rules from typical internet forums. I recommend you look at the site [tour] and [help] to see more site rules. Thanks.

Comment: I clicked on comment and it had no provision for adding a picture. Sorry not familiar with stack exchange sites - i read through what i thought i was supposed to do but must have missed something. Thanks for moving it. I will circle back and try to understand how to add a picture in a comment