# Can I use a 1kV capacitor for a 5V circuit?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, high-voltage, capacitance, low-voltage

In a [different question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13091/high-voltage-capacitor-in-a-low-voltage-system), it was asked if you could use a relatively higher voltage cap in a 5V circuit (35V cap). It seems that's ok, but I want to know if that logic is still applicable towards the extremes.

I have a 5V circuit, and am looking at a 1kV capacitor. Can I still use this without having to convert the capacitance or anything?

Comment: @Andyaka Just feels crazy that I wouldn't even have to use a different capacitance or something. I don't really know where my doubts are from

Comment: 3kV caps are often used for coupling uV level RF signals in order to prevent voltage breakdown failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. If you need a 10nF capacitor for a 5V circuit but only have 10nF capacitor available with 1kV rating then it can certainly be used.

Comment: Will there be *any* difference? I need to keep low impedance as this is part of a PS

Comment: @CATboardBETA There may well be a significant difference in impedance magnitude and tan-theta specs if the HV capacitor you're using is of a different construction to the one you're replacing, especially with such a large ratio between operating voltage and rated voltage. You'd have to check the datasheet for the specific replacement part and evaluate its properties against the specific design parameters.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I'm designing something in the nanofarad scale and lower voltage caps aren't available. I'm looking at a polypropylene.

Comment: @CATboardBETA What do you mean lower voltage capacitors aren't available in the nanofarad scale? You should be able to get 1nF caps in pretty much any voltage rating you want, from 3V to 3kV.

Comment: @Polynomial I haven't been able to find a 30nF THT capacitor.

Comment: @CATboardBETA I'm sensing an X/Y problem here. What are you specifically trying to do? What's the design problem you're running into?

Comment: @CATboardBETA 30nF is an odd value, look for 33nF (it's within 10% tolerance) and you should find thousands of suitable parts.

Comment: Well color me surprised. That does the trick.

Comment: @CATboardBETA Capacitor and resistor values come in standardised series. The values in each standard series are chosen such that the tolerance extremes of adjacent standard values meet or slightly overlap in the middle. For example, the E12 series has ±10% tolerance, and includes standard values such as 27, 33, 39, etc. - 27nF+10% is 29.7nF, and 33nF-10% is 29.7nF. 33nF+10% is 36.3nF, and 39nF-10% is 35.1nF. If you plotted the value ranges on a graph it'd be practically continuous from 0.1pF all the way up to 1mF and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

To be more direct: Voltage is only a rating usually determined by physical constraints like distance between the two metal contacts. It really has nothing to do with capacitance, which is defined by: plate area, distance between plates, and dielectric constant. From that you can see that the distance to achieve high voltage ratings means having more distance. If the part is marked with a certain value, it'll be that value. Just might be a little bit bigger than a lower voltage rated part

Answer (score 0):

If you're replacing a low voltage electrolytic with a high voltage electrolytic, this is generally fine. The rating on the capacitor is a maximum operating limit, not a prescription for the specific voltage you need to drive it at. For a general-purpose application like a smoothing cap on a DC input, picking a higher voltage capacitor like this shouldn't matter as long as the capacitance value matches what was there previously. The same generally goes for non-polar capacitors, depending on the exact application.

One thing to be aware of is that low voltage capacitors and high voltage capacitors typically have differing properties when it comes to ESR, impedance, leakage current, and maximum ripple current. Voltage also plays a role in derating of the capacitance - a 22uF 16V capacitor might behave more like a 10uF capacitor if you apply the full 16V - but this only usually matters if you're planning on lowering the voltage rating of the part rather than increasing it.

For scenarios like switching regulators, where ripple current and impedance matter more, you might need to double-check the datasheet ensure you don't run into self-heating problems. The same goes for decoupling capacitors - replacing a small low-voltage MLCC with a much larger HV capacitor might not be ideal.

For passive filters (e.g. RC, RLC) or high frequency / RF path stuff, you probably don't want to be replacing 16V MLCCs with 1kV polypropylene caps, because they'll behave very differently.

When it comes to part selection for designs, higher voltage capacitors often aren't available in larger capacitances, and if they are they cost more and/or take up more physical space - as a rule of thumb you generally want to try to pick capacitors rated for 150% to 200% of the expected operating voltage, referring to the derating information in the datasheet, to optimise for cost and size.